# How can I divide a <v-carousel-item> in <v-carousel> into two columns in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I want to implement the below carousel in vuetify3? How can I do that?
[image: carousel with two columns for any slide]

Comment: Can you provide some code details of what you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Grid` component inside of the Carousel.

```
<v-carousel
  cycle
  height="400"
  hide-delimiter-background
  show-arrows="hover"
>
  <v-carousel-item
    v-for="(color, i) in colors"
    :key="color"
  >
    <v-sheet
      :color="color"
      height="100%"
      tile
    >
      <v-row
        style="height:100%;"
        align="center"
        justify="center"
      >
        <v-col v-for="(i, index) in 2" :key="index">     
          <div class="text-h2 d-flex align-center justify-center">Column</div>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-sheet>
  </v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
```

Docs: https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/

Example: https://codepen.io/alexpetergill/pen/oNMoQae

Comment: Thanks, for some reason, I can not upload image, however this is exactly what I want